# Magento - Add comments to product reviews

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

On our e-commerce site, we get a lot of product reviews from people who had problems with our products. Many of these problems could be resolved by our customer service call center. I would like to know if there's a way to write a response to a customer's review so we can help customers troubleshoot, show off our company's excellent customer service skills, and negate some of the bad reviews on the site. These comments should show up on the front-end with the reviews, and only certain admin users should be allowed to submit a comment. Does anyone know of an extension or any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: do you need customer testimonial? this extension is used to show customer comment and so on,

Answer (score 0):

In magento there is a feature of giving review to the product,Which is not showing unless or until the admin approve the review from admin side **catelog-> Reviews and Rating -> Customer Reviews -> Pending Reviews** so it will show the list of review given by customer to that particular products so based on that you can able to get an idea about the reviews of customer regarding that products.

let me know if any queries still there

Comment: Our reviews are working and people can leave reviews on the site. What I'm looking for is the ability for our internal team to add a comment to the review that will be visible publicly. So when someone writes a review that says "This product is terrible," below it on the product page you would see a response from our customer service center that says "We're sorry you had trouble with the product. We'll email you to follow up on what we can do to help. Here's a link to some troubleshooting tips that might help too." The only way to do this now is to add the comment to the body of the review.

Comment: Guys, any solution to this. I have been looking for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Late on this, however this might helpful to others: there is an extension that does exactly this on Codecanyon: [Product Review Comments](http://codecanyon.net/item/product-review-comments/6942683)